# merge 2 preg_match_all together

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm attempting to find the name & image of a sticker within a **JSON** response from an API within PHP, I've managed to get the `preg_match_all` to find the **src** attribute, but I'm struggling to get it to work for the corresponding name of the image, here's my **JSON** response as a string

```
$string = '"<br><div id=\"sticker_info\" name=\"sticker_info\" title=\"Sticker Details\" style=\"border: 2px solid rgb(102, 102, 102); border-radius: 6px; width=100; margin:4px; padding:8px;\"><center><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/apps\/730\/icons\/econ\/stickers\/cologne2016\/sig_pasha.9f41c874350c06e9a902bea06a5228ceccb25ee1.png\"><img width=64 height=48 src=\"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/apps\/730\/icons\/econ\/stickers\/cluj2015\/vp.5cc950372e0c448d2ff958b7ce13fd907bcd2ace.png\"><br>Sticker: pashaBiceps | Cologne 2016, Virtus.Pro | Cluj-Napoca 2015<\/center><\/div>"';
```

We've managed get the img src using

```
preg_match_all('@src="([^"]+)"@', $string, $matches);
$arr = array_pop($matches);
```

This would return a simple array:

```
[
    "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/cologne2016/sig_pasha.9f41c874350c06e9a902bea06a5228ceccb25ee1.png", 
    "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/cluj2015/vp.5cc950372e0c448d2ff958b7ce13fd907bcd2ace.png"
]
```

I'm trying to get it to also show the item name for the image, they're in order just comma separated, somehow get an array like so:

```
[
    [
        'src' => 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/cologne2016/sig_pasha.9f41c874350c06e9a902bea06a5228ceccb25ee1.png',
        'name' => 'pashaBiceps | Cologne 2016'
    ],
    [
        'src' => 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/cluj2015/vp.5cc950372e0c448d2ff958b7ce13fd907bcd2ace.png',
        'name' => 'Virtus.Pro | Cluj-Napoca 2015'
    [
]
```

You can see from the `$string` that the images are also in order with the `Stickers:` text, I just don't know how to get them to merge without doing **dirty** hacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to:

1. Extract the names separately as a string
2. Break this string down into an array
3. Parse through the src and name arrays and push the values into a combined array.

Here's the code:

```
// Extract URLs and store them in an array
preg_match_all('@src="([^"]+)"@', $string, $matches);
$matches = array_pop($matches);

// Extract the names as a string and break it down into an array
preg_match('@Sticker\: ([^<]+)<\/center>@', $string, $matches2);
$matches2 = array_pop($matches2);
$matches2 = explode(', ', $matches2);

// Combine the two arrays
$combinedArr = array();
$numItems = count($matches);
for ($i = 0; $i < $numItems; ++$i) {
  $combinedArr[] = array('src' => $matches[$i], 'name' => $matches2[$i]);
}

print_r($combinedArr);
```

`$combinedArr` will contain:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [src] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/cologne2016/sig_pasha.9f41c874350c06e9a902bea06a5228ceccb25ee1.png
            [name] => pashaBiceps | Cologne 2016
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [src] => https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/730/icons/econ/stickers/cluj2015/vp.5cc950372e0c448d2ff958b7ce13fd907bcd2ace.png
            [name] => Virtus.Pro | Cluj-Napoca 2015
        )
)
```